# Customizing model app_label does not work with django 1.4?

Tags: python, django

I made a very simple application to store variables that can be edited onto django admin interface :

the model is simple :

```
class LiveGlobal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,primary_key=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s = %s (%s)' % (self.name,self.value,self.comment)
```

admin too :

```
class LiveGlobalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('name','value','comment')
    search_fields = ('name','value','comment')
admin.site.register(LiveGlobal, LiveGlobalAdmin)
```

It works well, but now I want to change 'Live global' into 'global variables' onto admin index page, to do so I put in the model :

```
class Meta:
        app_label = 'Global variables'
```

But I got this message onto admin interface :

```
Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'Global variables'}' not found.
```

Why ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your app_label, somthing like this:

```
app_label = 'global_variables'
```

Lowercase and without spaces

Comment: It works, but it modifies the SQL table name, so if you have already data into, you need to do some little sql admin...

Comment: Oki, but I think that django does not support something like this... And this would not be in the meta of the model